# WYSIHTML5 - Text Input is not being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I have an "edit modal" with a textarea that is populated by an API response. It works just fine.
When I activate WYSIHTML5, the textarea returns empty. I have tried other rich text editors, but all of them don't let the textarea be populated. Is there any way that I can make it work?

Here, I call the API:

```js
$('.btnEditNews').live('click', function () {

        var data = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var jsonResponse;

        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (this.readyState === 4) {
            jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.response)['singleNews'];
            $('#titleNews').val(jsonResponse.title);
            $('#textNewsBody').html(jsonResponse.newsText);
            $('#imgNews').attr('src', jsonResponse.file);
          }
        });

        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.send(data);

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Calling the WYSIHTML5:

```js
$('#textNewsBody').wysihtml5({
      "font-styles": true, //Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc. Default true
      "emphasis": true, //Italics, bold, etc. Default true
      "lists": true, //(Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers. Default true
      "html": false, //Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML. Default false
      "link": false, //Button to insert a link. Default true
      "image": false, //Button to insert an image. Default true,
      "color": false //Button to change color of font  
    });
```

```html
<script src="lib/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I found the solution! Instead of **$('#textNewsBody').html(jsonResponse.newsText);** I did **$('#textarea-id').data("wysihtml5").editor.setValue('new content');**